# Change R library directory in Linux

Tags: r, linux, linux-mint

I am starting to learn R programming in Linux Mint 20 (Ubuntu 20.04 based) so I installed R 4.0.2 because it is last in the R repo. I am also using Rstudio.
My problem is that, even I configured Rstudio to work in a specific folder when not in a project, different from home (`~`), the 'R' folder is still being created in the home for the libraries even though I did not installed anything. Is any way to change it? Searching here I found that `setwd` could work but I don't know how to use it and if it is permanent or not.
Any help? if I forgot any information please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command below I was able to install `dplyr` in a custom location.

```
install.packages("dplyr", lib = "<custom_location>")
```

When the argument `lib` is missing, the first path returned by `.libPaths()` is used. At the moment this should point to your home. These paths are set in R configuration files. I was able to overwrite the `R_LIBS_USER` enviroment variable at user level, setting it in a `.Renviron` file created in my home.

In other words, just create a blank file in your HOME folder and name it .Renviron,  then open it with your preferred editor and add:

```
R_LIBS_USER=/your/specific/folder
```

Changing /your/specific/folder for your preferred destination, like ~/home/*user*/R